# Implement retry logic with Mutiny

Tags: kotlin, mutiny

I'm just learning Mutiny and I need to implement retry logic.

I have this code:

```
fun main() {
    getResult()
        .onFailure().invoke { t -> println("Got error: $t") }
        .onFailure().retry().atMost(2)
        .subscribe().with(
            { result -> println(result) },
            { t -> t.printStackTrace() }
        )
}

fun getResult(): Uni<String?> {
    println("Preparing result...")

    return Uni.createFrom().failure(Exception("Some error happened"))
}
```

So, the `getResult()` is a function that may misbehave and needs to be called multiple times on failure.

When I run this program, this is what's happening:

```
Preparing result...
Got error: java.lang.Exception: Some error happened
Got error: java.lang.Exception: Some error happened
Got error: java.lang.Exception: Some error happened
java.lang.Exception: Some error happened
    at MainKt.getResult(Main.kt:16)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:4)
```

Obiously, the `getResult()` function is called only once, while the `onFailure()` stages actually executed three times.

Is there anything that Mutiny could help me to execute `getResult()` function on each failure? I sure can implement this with a simple loop, but I feel like Mutiny should already have something like this.

Unfortunately, I didn't find anything suitable in the docs.

Comment: Looks to me like 1 failure and 2 retries = 3. You’re missing that it doesn’t call `getResult` again, it _resubscribes_ to the `Uni` 3 times.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wrote. I'd like to know, what is the best practice in Mutiny to actually call `getResult` on each retry, is there a ready to use utility for this or I just have to use a plain loop?

Comment: Defer it and flatmap it.

Comment: Thank you, it worked with `Uni.createFrom().deferred()`. The only problem is `deferred()` doesn't allow null items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the right solution for this is actually using the `Uni.deferred()` method like this:

```
fun main() {
    Uni.createFrom().deferred { getResult() }
        .onFailure().invoke { t -> println("Got error: $t") }
        .onFailure().retry().atMost(2)
        .subscribe().with(
            { result -> println(result) },
            { t -> t.printStackTrace() }
        )
}
```

Thanks to Boris the Spider, who suggested to use the `deferred()`, and to Clement, who clarified its use with null values.

Initially, I misinterpreted the `deferred()` documentation thinking it's not allowed to return a null value, but actually it's OK for a `Supplier` to return a `Uni` of null:

`Uni.createFrom.deferred { Uni.createFrom().nullItem() }`

What the docs really are prohibiting is returning a null instead of a `Uni`:

`Uni.createFrom().deferred { null }`

Answer (score 2):

Your Uni in `getResult` is created with an "immediate" item, which is cached and never computed again.

Use  `Uni.createFrom().failure(() -> Exception("Some error happened"))`

In this case, it's a supplier, so it won't be cached but called on every attempt.

Comment: The problem here is the `getResult()` is an external library method I have no control over, so I can change only the way it invoked in my code. Right now I'm using `Uni.createFrom().nullItem<Void>().flatMap { getResult() }`. It works but looks kinda messy.

Comment: What is the return type of gerResult() ? Is it blocking?
I would recommend to NOT use flatMap, except if you understand what it actually does.

Comment: The return type of the `getResult()` is `Uni<String>`, it is non-blocking.

Comment: Ah great! So, you can either use it directly or do `Uni.createFrom().deferred(() -> getResult())`. The later make sure you re-execute the getResult operation on every retry. The former will depend whether `getResult` returned a cached value.

Comment: Sorry, I provided incorrect type for the `getResult()`. Actually it's Uni<String?>, so it can return null, and `deferred()` doesn't allow this.

Comment: Do you mean that `getResult()` can return `null` or emit a `null` valid. The latter is usual for `Uni` (`Uni` can emit `null`). The former is a bit odd, and it is likely to be an API design issue. Anyway, use something like in the deferred supplier: `Uni<String> uni = getResult();  if (uni == null) return Uni.createFrom().nullItem(); return uni;`

Comment: The `getResult()` may emit null as a valid value.
Just now I realized that `deferred` actually returns a `Uni` and not a raw value itself, so it's OK to return a `Uni` of null or Void. Thank you, I'm sorry it took me so long to get it. 
I incorrectly interpreted the line from `deferred()` docs: "supplier – the supplier, must not be null, must not produce null"